# iOS - Retrieve cell titles in parent view from an embedded UITableView within a container

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parent-child

Afternoon!

Im trying to get the UITableViewCells title text from its parent view, The UITableView in embedded through a container..

Heres an image to show my layout:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBOAt.jpg

The button has an IBAction that adds the rest of my data into pointers then saves the object..

So ideally i would say:

```
NSString *CellTitlePoint = childview.cell.title.text;

[NewObject setObject: CellTitlePointer forKey:@"NewObjectKey"];
```

But obviously it doesn't work like that!

Im not too sure how much more detail i can into, I've seen a few questions similar like this but none have really answered my specific question.. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: The parent controller has an array, childViewControllers. You can access the child from the parent with that.

Answer (score 1):

You have the wrong approach. Table views take care of displaying data from a data source into the table view. You don't manipulate the fields directly - you let the table view take care of it.

If you want to change the data, you change your data model (usually an array of some sort) and then tell the table view to update one or more cells. At the simplest, you can call the table view's reloadData method, which completely reloads the contents. If you've only changed the values of certain cells, it's often better to tell the table view to just update those cells, using a method like `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:`.

Also, it's best to let your embedded table view controller manage the table view for you. Subclass UITableViewController and create methods in the subclass that let the parent VC notify the table view controller about changes to the data.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Duncan, I have the table views working fine.. Im saving an object from the Parent to Parse and one its columns needs to be the Title from the cells within the UITableView.. so i need to retrieve the cell title, send it to the parent, then save the object with the cell title within that.

Comment: No, you don't need to retrieve the cell title. You need to retrieve the current value of the title property for that index in your data model. The table view controller should be reading/writing data to the data model, and you should fetch the data from the model. If you are reading values from cell titles, you are making a design mistake.